Why is there .php files in my Nextjs v14 static site which is deployed on Vercel?
I was checking my Vercel hobby plan's bandwidth usage of last 30 days and I found that there's bandwidth usage of PHP files, which my project doesn't have, because its a static site, which is not calling a single REST API or anything, and My portfolio website is developed in NextJs 14 App Directory
I know Nextjs doesn't use PHP or anything, and besides that, I've not developed any APIs in Nextjs as well, its a very.
Am I hacked, is someone using my Vercel to host their own PHP project?
Some files names are prefixed with "wp" but I've never used wordpress in my life
I can provide more info if required, just ask me

I wanna know why there's PHP files requested from my server and served, and how to stop

Visit https://stackoverflow.com/foo.php. A PHP file has been requested from StackOverflow, which doesn't support PHP. The resulting 404 page uses a little bit of bandwidth. This is what is happening to you, as well.

As per ceejayoz's answer
When pages with .php extension are requested, but because those pages doesn't exist, my NextJs App send 404 page instead, so the bandwidth used is because Vercel is sending a 404 page in response

You are not hacked, these are bots attempting any known Wordpress (and any other popular PHP backed apps) attack vectors and its being reported in your access logs. If you have a firewall in front of your application, you can have it block all .php requests.

If there's not .php files, and server is not sending any in return, then how is network bandwidth used?

It's probably reporting the incoming network bandwidth. So the bot issuing the requests is providing large request bodies as an attack vector.
